# Laravel flush tag not always flushing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, redis

I'm using redis with Laravel 4.2. Occasionally when I do this:

`Cache::tags('products', 'list-products')->flush()`

it flushes **most** items but 1 or 2 may stick around. They're not being reinserted as I'm checking for that (and sometimes I'm deleting the MySQL object they're caching) and so I have to manually go into the redis server and delete those keys (which happen to match the given tags).

Is there a way around it? Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: If you run that line of code twice, will it flush all the items?

Comment: I would think that some other process is inserting new items after you do the flush.  Are you sure that isn't the case?

Answer (score 1):

It was 6 years ago but I've been looking around because of a similar issue so I wanted to share my findings. Turns out Laravel tags functionality is flawed to the core. Some of items might be left just because they had single tag, either products or list-products. Because of it you need to put exactly the same tags you tagged your item with. Also it would not work at all if you switched the order of tags (tried it). The only way is to use alternative packages for cache management avoiding laravel. https://github.com/swayok/alternative-laravel-cache here is one of them (probably, I found only this one) but Laravel 9 is not supported yet :|